# CrateIO 2.0.2 - Problems with Insert and Update

Tags: cratedb

I've done an upgrade from Crate 1.1.4 to 2.0.2. After this I've also optimized all tables.

Crate runs at one server with one instance. I have not changed any default settings, except the node name and the cluster name.

But now I can't write anything at the database. Selects are good, but every write operation ends up with:

```
SQLActionException: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 5000 UnavailableShardsException: [mytable][3] Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] (have 1, needed 2). Timeout: [1m], request: [ShardUpsertRequest{items=[Item{id='10'}], shardId=[my_table][3]}]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation.execute(ReplicationOperation.java:107)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:319)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:254)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:839)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:836)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationsLock.acquire(IndexShardOperationsLock.java:142)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquirePrimaryOperationLock(IndexShard.java:1656)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.acquirePrimaryShardReference(TransportReplicationAction.java:848)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:271)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:250)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:242)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6.doRun(TransportService.java:550)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:527)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It does not matter if I do the INSERT/UPDATE query with JDBC or directly at the Crate console.

Did anyone has a good idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CrateDB changed the default write consistency checks and also the default `number_of_shards` (to allow usage on a 1-node cluster with default table  settings).

See https://crate.io/docs/reference/release_notes/2.0.1.html#breaking-changes

In your case, I guess your `number_of_replicas` is set to `1`.
Setting it to `0` or `0-1` (auto-expand) will solve this.